# I get a message of android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT t_id,created_at,csurname,servicename FROM " + TABLE_TASKS
            + " INNER JOIN customers ON c_id = c_id " + " INNER JOIN s_id = s_id";
```

where I am wrong?

Comment: The second inner join is missing a table name and if your column names are the same you need table name aliases i.e. `customers c on c_id = c.c_id`

Comment: You are right about the missing table but instead near = says near . there is an error

Comment: Try `SELECT t_id,created_at,csurname,servicename FROM tasks t inner join customers c on t.c_id = c.c_id` - I dont have enough information to fix your second inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the third table name:

```
INNER JOIN s_id = s_id
          ^ YourThirdTable ON
```

And as giannisf mentioned, `c_id` and `s_id` will be ambiguous without specifying the table name. However, with the same column name in both tables, you can use the USING clause instead:

```
SELECT t_id,created_at,csurname,servicename
FROM Tasks
INNER JOIN customers USING (c_id)
INNER JOIN YourThirdTable USING (s_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need table identifiers.

use the `as` keyword to name the `TABLE_TASKS` table and then on `JOIN` use that name

example:

`tasks.c_id = other_table.c_id`;